# R: convert data frame values from integer to double based on the column index

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame, where each column corresponds to variable and each row corresponds to the numerical category, e.g. 0, 1 or 2.

```
df <- data.frame(TKI=c(1,1,2,0,1),
                 Chemo=c(1,2,2,0,1),
                 Radio=c(1,1,2,0,1),
                 EGFR=c(1,2,2,0,1),
                 ALK=c(1,1,2,0,1))
df

  TKI Chemo Radio EGFR ALK
1   1     1     1    1   1
2   1     2     1    2   1
3   2     2     2    2   2
4   0     0     0    0   0
5   1     1     1    1   1
```

I would like to convert each value to the double based on the column index. For example, the aforementioned table will be transformed into this:

```
 1.1 2.1 3.1 4.1 5.1
 1.1 2.2 3.1 4.2 5.1
 1.2 2.2 3.2 4.2 5.2
 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0
 1.1 2.1 3.1 4.1 5.1
```

I also would like to obtain the list of columns and their indexes, such as this:

```
1 - TKI
2 - Chemo
3 - Radio
4 - EGFR
5 - ALK
```

How can I do this conversion?

Thank you for your time and help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `col` to get the column index and divide the dataframe by 10 to create a decimal value and add the two numbers together.

```
col(df) + df/10

#  TKI Chemo Radio EGFR ALK
#1 1.1   2.1   3.1  4.1 5.1
#2 1.1   2.2   3.1  4.2 5.1
#3 1.2   2.2   3.2  4.2 5.2
#4 1.0   2.0   3.0  4.0 5.0
#5 1.1   2.1   3.1  4.1 5.1
```

To get column names and their position you can do :

```
ref_df <- data.frame(index = seq_along(df),
                     names = names(df))

#  index names
#1     1   TKI
#2     2 Chemo
#3     3 Radio
#4     4  EGFR
#5     5   ALK
```